# How to push site columns updates to content types

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

here's my scenario: a wrote a job definition that updates a MultiChoice site column, filling in with audiences:

```
<Field ID="{fcc46300-de6e-481e-ac2c-000000000001}"
       Name="Audiences"
       DisplayName="$Resources:Project,Audiences;"
       Type="MultiChoice"
```

Thing is, if I add the site column directly to a list, I see the choices. But, if the same site column is being added through a content type that references it, I don't see the choices.

I understand that SharePoint creates copies of content types and fields for each list, but - how should I be able to update the content types to include the changes made to the site column? I'm having trouble doing that.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I finally decided, as a workaround, to push the changes to the copy of the field present in each list. That obviously works. Which makes me think about the nature of content types as artifacts for creation time, leaving the objects brought to each list through the content type carry their own lives... isn't that a descriptive metaphor?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question once.
You should be able to use content type usages.
Please refer to my question here:
[Sharepoint - add field to content type not updating the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606791/sharepoint-add-field-to-content-type-not-updating-the-list)
Thanks,
Joseph

Answer (score 0):

You can add New fields and change names in SharePoint Designer but for changes that reflect in the List I would use the Site Settings_Site Columns to make those changes